# Redirect user if url matches certain conditions

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

I'd like the user to be redirected to a new webpage if the url contains certain conditions. I can't seem to get the OR condition to work. Any thoughts?

```
if (
    document.location.href.indexOf("https://www.oct.ca/") > -1 &&
    document.location.href.indexOf("professionally_speaking") > -1 &&
    document.location.href.includes("2019-03" || "2018-12")
  ) {
    window.location = window.location.href.replace("https://www.oct.ca/", "http://professionallyspeaking.oct.ca/")

  }
```

Comment: The `includes` method doesn't accept that Boolean condition (which is simply always true). It sounds ok when you read it, but it doesn't make JavaScript sense. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that - add another condition:

```
&& (document.location.href.includes("2019-03") || document.location.href.includes("2018-12"))
```

Comment: You need parentheses around those. As it is, this would pass if the URL was something completely unwanted like `http://foo.bar/2018-12`.

Comment: No worries @user3175043, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted.